# Why does option recompile make this query run ~10 times faster (even after sp_updatestats)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a relatively simple query, I have an event table and I want to query all records with a date within the last 12 to next 12 hours. The table has ~1 million rows.

When I run the query with option (recompile) it takes around 25ms, without option (recompile) it takes around 250ms. I have run sp_updatestats and it did not make a difference.

```
Declare
@EventDateTimeHoursBack int = 12,
@EventDateTimeHoursForward int = 12

Declare
    @BackTime datetime = DATEADD(HOUR, -@EventDateTimeHoursBack, GETUTCDATE()),
    @ForwardTime datetime = DATEADD(HOUR, @EventDateTimeHoursForward, GETUTCDATE())

Select
        *
    From
        dbo.Event 
    Where
        EventDateUtc >= @BackTime
        and EventDateUtc <= @ForwardTime
    Option (Recompile)
```

This is the query plan **with** option recompile

[image: With option recompile query plan]

This is the query plan **without** option recompile

[image: Without option recompile query plan]

Comment: I would ask do you need the `*`? If you limit the query to the columns you *actually* need, what is performance like? The first query plan suggests that you don't have a covering index, and so a key lookup is being used, where as the latter a *full table scan*. If you had covering index, I expect the query would be faster still.

Comment: If the bad plan was compiled that way because it used an atypical parameter (say, 1000 hours ago instead of 12), updating stats doesn't change the fact that the best operation in that case is a scan. (Also, [don't use `sp_updatestats`](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/07/sql-statistics/statistics-updates).)

Comment: @Larnu limiting the columns does improve the speed, however in this case I do actually need all the columns. I suppose I could increase speed by selecting the IDs into a temp table or subquery first and then join to the remaining columns after, however that doesn't feel any cleaner than just using recompile in the first place.

Comment: @AaronBertrand There seems to be a lot of advice on here about running sp_updatestats in situations like this. If what you say is the case (which it could be), how do I force it to use the quicker plan for the 99% use case.

Comment: The way you force it to consider the actual parameters at runtime, instead of using a plan that may have been cached with different parameters, is to use option recompile. Updating stats (using a different method) will only help you when your parameters are outside the range the current stats know about.